# Emacs forces Gnome logout under Debian Wheezy?

Tags: debian, emacs, gnome, crash

I am running Debian Wheezy 64bit with the latest Nvidia drivers (from Nvidia). Whenever I fire "emacs" (Emacs23.4), Gnome session goes dark and it logs out and bring back the log in menu consistently. And so far this is the only app does that. I am puzzled because I am unabel  to debug this issue.

I am puzzled with this peculiar problem. And I am hoping that someone can help me out this bizarre occurence. It must be something to do with graphics display because it almost feels like Gdm crashes but I cannot be sure.

Are there features in Emacs that can casue such an issue? I tried default emacs settings. However Gtk Vim runs just fine ;)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

My resolving for similar problem:

**Error:**

Launching binary files or .ics or opening System settings causes log out

**Solution:**

Update kernel
old version: `3.2.0-4-amd64`
new version: `3.9-0.bpo.1-amd64`

**Installing:**

```
$ su root
$ echo "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ wheezy-backports main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && apt-get update
$ aptitude -t wheezy-backports install linux-image-3.9-0.bpo.1-amd64
$ aptitude -t wheezy-backports install linux-headers-3.9-0.bpo.1-amd64
$ sudo reboot
```

**Problem:**

GDM is not started

**Error:**

Module Nvidia not found

**Solution:**

You need to install graphic drivers again for new kernel.

**Reinstall nVidia drivers:**

```
$ cd ~/Downloads/
$ sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-319.17.run
There appears to already be a driver installed on your system (version: 319.17). As part of installing this driver (version: 319.17), the existing driver will be uninstalled. Are you sure you want to continue?  
Yes  
Would you like to register the kernel module sources with DKMS? This will allow DKMS to automatically build a new module, if you install a different kernel later.  
No
```